# How can I edit the task app to contain updates on the task?

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, tasks, task-list

I would like to be able to see the tasks as they are now which an extra column - a line or two of a current update status. However, I want to be able to view the old update statuses to see how things progressed. Is there a way to edit the current task app to do this?

Comment: I'm thinking there may be a way to just have the "description" column only show the last line or two of the text in it. ideas?

Comment: Would the OOB item versioning functionality be adequate?  If you turn on versioning for the list, you can see all the accumulated changes in the version history.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Cool, I will add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on versioning for the list, you will be able to see the accumulated changes in the version history of each item.